# Error inserting data into PostGIS/PostgreSQL database through postgres_fdw Foreign Data Wrapper

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to insert data (a line geometry) into a foreign table which was mapped from a view in a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database. That view in turn, check if the the line is inside a polygon before inserting into a table.
Every time I insert data, PostgreSQL generate an error:

```
CRITICAL    Layer my_line_layer : PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR: function st_contains(public.geometry, public.geometry) does not exist
             HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
              CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function my_schema.my_line_layer_dml() line 4 at IF
              remote SQL command: INSERT INTO my_schema.my_line_layer(id, geom, name) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id
```

I checked that function ST_Contains exists in public schema, I can connect to the remote server and insert data directly into the same view without any problem.

Comment: Maybe you should use ogr_fdw instead of postgres_fdw. See https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/querying-spatial-data-with-postgis-and-ogr_fdw.

Comment: @user30184 from GitHub page of ogr_fdw: This is only for testing, for best performance you should use postgres_fdw foreign data wrapper even when querying a PostGIS enabled database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search path of the user used for the remote connection is restricted to the current schema. The trigger or view-function must therefore add `public` to its path (or whichever schema contains `postgis`). At the very end of the function, add `SET search_path = public;`

Comment: I tried putting "SET search_path = public;" at the end of the function as per your suggestion and the error was still raised. The problem was fixed when I put it at the beginning of the function. Please change your answer accordingly so that I can accept it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @CaoMinhTu :-) great that it is working. As per the [`create function` definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), the order of some options doesn't matter, so it is fine to have the `SET ..` at various places, including at the very end, as long as it is not inside the `sql body` section of course. (PS: and I use it successfully at the end, i.e.`... END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SET search_path = public;`)